# How to implement RESTful service in Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-services, rest

For educational and prototyping purposes I would like to learn how to implement simple RESTful service in Ruby without using some big framework like RoR.

I found a lot of examples hoe to do it in RoR, or how to implement self-serviced SOAP services, buy I could not find something similar for REST.

Can you provide any link to such an examples. Or if it's more complicated than I think (looking at the SOAP4R), any explanation of why?

Or, as I'm just starting to look deeper in Ruby, what are the basics of setting up a web application (different than RoR) - i.e. server bindings, app server parts, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Look at how Rack works, and then see how Sinatra builds on top of that to make development easier.

Comment: @coreyward: why not put an answer, so it can be voted, and eventually accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ditto coreyward. Take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It's pretty simple and you can throw some stuff together pretty quickly.